# iPhone Core Data - restrict returned results to future events

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a data store of events, however I only want to show events that occur in the future.

I have a field denoting the date of the event of type NSDate.

How do I filter events that have an NSDate * date time in the past?

Thanks

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Events" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"eventDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];



NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add a fetch predicate, an instance of NSPredicate. You're allowed to use the standard comparisons `<` and `>` in the predicate when creating it, so you can simply do:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date > %@",
                                                           [NSDate date]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Then execute your request as normal. The predicate will filter out all results that don't meet the criteria `date > [NSDate date]`, i.e. dates that are older than now. (This assumes your date field for your Core Data objects is called `date`; adjust accordingly if it's something else.)

For more info about predicates, you can see:

- The Predicate Programming Guide, [Creating Predicates](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793) section
- The [Predicate Format String Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB)
- The [NSPredicate class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)